# How do I force a download of xml in python?

Tags: python, xml

I know there are several threads on this, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.
This is the code that is erroring:

```
   print 'Content-Type: text/xml \n'
   print 'Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="test.qwc" \n'
   print 'Content-Length:' + len(xml)
   print xml
```

the xml variable is simply a string of xml. The xml is fine because I can get it to print into a browser. but when I add the Content-Disposition and Content-Length lines it gives me this error:

```
   XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
   Location: http:/myurl/XMLqwc.py?franchiseid=1
   Line Number 1, Column 31:
   Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="test.qwc" 
   ------------------------------^
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the "it" that is giving you an error?

Comment: The only word relevant to the question in the title or the tags is "python".

Answer (score 3):

1. This can't be the code you used to serve the XML because `"string" + len(whatever)` is guaranteed to be an exception.
2. You are adding two newlines instead of one to each header line, so your header will contain only the first line. The header and the body are separated by two newlines, you're putting two right after the first header. The rest goes to the XML.
3. I wouldn't use `print` for anything but simple text formats. HTTP is not so simple (see 3), you should use `sys.stdout.write()` instead.
4. There are dozens of [web frameworks for Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks). You should consider them instead. Some of them are very simple, such as Werkzeug and web.py.

Answer (score 2):

Headers and payload must be always separated by an empty line. The content-length header line is not even containing a line feed...in addition adding an integer (len()..) to a string looks weird.